# BigTop repo server 403 error

Tags: linux, fedora, bigtop, bigdata

I am currently trying to install BigTop on my fedora17 machine but i ran into a problem and i don't know what is wrong.

I followed the steps on https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/BIGTOP/How+to+install+Hadoop+distribution+from+Bigtop+0.5.0
but when I try to update my packages or search for a specific package i get a 403. does anyone know what's wrong ?

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the same - so while not helpful - it's not just you...

Comment: I am not sure but i thing the PGP-keys are deprecated. i changed to the 1.1.0 version and that seemed to work so if that is any help for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately we lost all the installable packages prior to 1.0.0 during the migration of our backend storage. You can still build them up using the source code, but I don't recommend that way since you need to prepare the build environment, which is quite complicated.

For now we have 1.0.0, 1.1.0, and 1.2.0 binary packages on the shelf for you to quickly consume and get your cluster up and running. Please visit our website:

http://bigtop.apache.org/download.html#releases

And feel free to reach our the community's user list (user@bigtop.apache.org). We'd love to help.